# Apache Flink dynamic number of Sinks

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using Apache Flink and the KafkaConsumer to read some values from a Kafka Topic. 
I also have a stream obtained from reading a file.

Depending on the received values, I would like to write this stream on different Kafka Topics.

Basically, I have a network with a leader linked to many children. For each child, the Leader needs to write the stream read in a child-specific Kafka Topic, so that the child can read it. 
When the child is started, it registers itself in the Kafka topic read from the Leader. 
The problem is that I don't know a priori how many children I have.

For example, I read `1` from the Kafka Topic, I want to write the stream in just one Kafka Topic named `Topic1`.
I read `1-2`, I want to write on two Kafka Topics (`Topic1` and `Topic2`).

I don't know if it is possible because in order to write on the Topic, I am using the Kafka Producer along with the `addSink` method and to my understanding (and from my attempts) it seems that Flink requires to know the number of sinks a priori.

But then, is there no way to obtain such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem well, I think you can solve it with a single sink, since you can choose the Kafka topic based on the record being processed. It also seems that one element from the source might be written to more than one topic, in which case you would need a [FlatMapFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FlatMapFunction.html) to replicate each source record N times (one for each output topic). I would recommend to output as a pair (aka `Tuple2`) with (topic, record).

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<String, MyValue>> stream = input.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<>() {
    public void flatMap(MyValue value, Collector<Tupple2<String, MyValue>> out) {
        for (String topic : topics) {
            out.collect(Tuple2.of(topic, value));
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can use the topic previously computed by creating the [FlinkKafkaProducer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer010.html) with a [KeyedSerializationSchema](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/util/serialization/KeyedSerializationSchema.html) in which you implement `getTargetTopic` to return the first element of the pair.

```java
stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer10<>(
        "default-topic",
        new KeyedSerializationSchema<>() {
            public String getTargetTopic(Tuple2<String, MyValue> element) {
                return element.f0;
            }
            ...
        },
        kafkaProperties)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyedSerializationSchema
Is now deprecated. Instead you have to use "KafkaSerializationSchema"

The same can be achieved by overriding the serialize method.

```
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(
String inputString, @Nullable Long aLong){ 
        return new ProducerRecord<>(customTopicName,
 key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), inputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```