# Can Flink write to multiple Kafka topics using a transactional binding?

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, apache-flink

Is there a way to sink records using KafkaSink to more than one topic ensuring transactions? The documentation does not mention anything like it.

There is [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426225) which proposes collecting the same record multiple times and routing them to different topics. My concern here is the process failing in the middle of the writing phase. Would it have a transaction binding among all sinks originated from the same source?  I mean, could I end up with a committed record in one topic but not in the other one? I was expecting something like a [KafkaTemplate as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865968/write-to-two-kafka-topics-in-a-single-transaction-using-spring-kafka).

The destination topics is derived from a property of the event and a config file, think of something like a fanout with events landing into 1 or more topics. Ideally, if there is more than 1 topic, a Kafka transaction would be use to push the event.

Using `out.collect` multiple times would, in essense, give me the expected output. But I'm concerned about the transactional binding among those writes. I could end up with the sink record in one topic but not on the others due to a failure on sink time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should all just work without any effort on your part, regardless of how many topics or brokers are involved. (However, it is currently the case that data can be lost. See the final paragraph below.)

Flink's KafkaSink uses a two-phase commit protocol. According to the contract of this two-phase commit, once transactions are pre-committed, all participants are obliged to be able to commit them.

During the pre-commit phase the KafkaSink flushes any pending writes ahead of the checkpoint barrier, and stores the transaction ID in the checkpoint. Only after every task has completed the pre-commit phase will the checkpoint coordinator signal to all of the tasks that the checkpoint is complete. Only at this point is the pre-commit phase complete.

Assuming that all of the sinks obey the two-phase commit contract (and subsequently actually commit those transactions), then all of the transactions across the various sinks will ultimately be committed. These transactions will include all of the data in front of the checkpoint barriers, and none of the data behind those barriers. And if anything failed before the checkpoint was complete, everything everywhere will be rolled back.

So when might this fail? It is currently the case that if a Kafka transaction times out, data will be lost. Work is underway to correct this flaw; see [FLIP-319: Integrate with Kafka's Support for Proper 2PC Participation (KIP-939)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/3hU0Dw) and [KIP-939: Support Participation in 2PC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/qxU0Dw).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, just want to double-check something. Will the transaction commit happen on the checkpointing phase (so as the committing offsets from the source)?

Comment: Yes, the transactions are committed in concert with the checkpoints.